# How to split a big ODS file without causing memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, mysql, excel, memory, ods

I'm working with a MYSQL database, and have two types of files to import:
First one is a ***CSV*** file that I can use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path-to-csv_file'
```

The second type of file is ***ODS*** (OpenDocument Spreadsheet) that MYSQL doesn't support for `LOAD DATA INFILE`.
My solution was to convert ODS to CSV using [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) package that have a `XLSX.readfile` command and then using [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer). But, when working with large ODS files, my program was crashing cause it was using to much memory. I searched for solutions and found [streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) but xlsx package doesn't have read streams. After this, I tried to use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) cause it has a `fs.createReadStream` command, but this module doesn't support ODS files. An example is comparing both returns in `fs.readFile` and `xlsx.readFile`.

***fs.readFile:***

```
PK♥♦m�IQ�l9�.mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheetPK♥♦m�IQM◄ˋ%�%↑Thumbnails/thumbnail.png�PNG
→
IHDR�♥A�-=♥PLTE►►☼§¶►∟↓*.!/<22/8768:G6AN>AM>BP>MaC:;A?GOE?EFJGJRJQ[TJEQOQ\QJYWYKVeX\dX]p\bkXetaNJgTEe[Wp^Wa_aja\ue\hfgektjqztkeqnpyqlwwvco�jw�j}�v{�q⌂�~�⌂{��t��t��u��z��y��|��{��{��}���o]�od�vj�|v�⌂n�⌂r��{��n��x��~��~������
```

***XLSX.readFile:***

```
  J323: { t: 's', v: '79770000', w: '79770000' },
  K323: { t: 's', v: '20200115', w: '20200115' },
```

Working with XLSX module is easy, cause I can pick up only the data that I want in this ODS file. Using a javascript code, I extract three columns and put it in an array:

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
let posts = [];
let post = {};
for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    let filePath = `C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\file_users.ODS`;
    
    let workbook = xlsx.readFile(filePath);
    let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];


    for (let cell in worksheet) {
        const cellAsString = cell.toString();
        cellAsString[0] === 'A' ? post['ID'] = worksheet[cell].v :
            cellAsString[0] === 'C' ? post['USER NAME'] = worksheet[cell].v : null;
    
        if (cellAsString[0] === 'J') {
            post['USER EMAIL'] = worksheet[cell].v;
            Object.keys(post).length == 3 ? posts.push(post) : null;
            post = {}
        }
    }
}
```

...returns:

```
{
    ID: '1',
    'USER NAME': 'John Paul',
    'USER EMAIL': 'Paul.John12@hotmail.com'
  },
  {
    ID: '2',
    'USER NAME': 'Julia',
    'USER EMAIL': 'lejulie31312@outlook.com'
  },
  {
    ID: '3',
    'USER NAME': 'Greg Norton',
    'USER EMAIL': 'thenorton31031@hotmail.com'
  },
  ... 44660 more items
```

So, my problem is when working with large ODS files. The return above is when using this script with 78MB file, and is using 1.600MB of RAM. When I try to use this with 900MB files, my memory reaches the limit (4000MB+) and I got the error: `'ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG'`

I tried to use [readline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline) package for parse the data, but it needs a stream.

If I have to slice the ODS files into small pieces, how could I read the file for this without crashing my vs code?